# Benefits of using System.Runtime.Caching over ServiceStack MemoryCacheClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I have a MVC 4 site that is load balanced (sticky bits enabled) in the cloud and my caching needs are very simple, just take some of the load off the database. Currently we are using System.Runtime.Caching but I've had to bolt on a few features, namely a collection of cached items and I really would like to move to ServiceStack's MemoryCacheClient. Are there any reasons for or against such a move?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what features of ASP.NET's `Runtime.Caching` you're actually using and whether or not they're supplemented by [ServiceStack's Caching providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). E.g. Runtime.Caching has the opportunity to expire a cache entry and fire a callback when an entry has expired. ServiceStack caching doesn't have this feature.

Other than that, they're both thread-safe and in-memory so performance shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: I don't need a callback when the entry expires, fairly simple. If my needs change at some point I'll just swap in another more robust distributed cache i.e. Redis